# Angular 2: Jasmine: Why value is not updated when calling onClick method in unit testing

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have created an app using angular cli and I am writing unit tests using jasmine and Karma as their runner.
I have a component with a value named x which updated whenever user click a button(cancel button). I have written a unit test case in which I am testing two things. I have written both in one it, I comment the other one while testing the other one.
1. Is my button is clickable 
2. changing value of x from blank to 'changed'.

My first test is passing but second is failing. Can somebody help ? 
Below are my code files.

```
//app.component.ts
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { Http } from '@angular/http';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })
    export class AppComponent {
      constructor(private http: Http) {

      }
      title = 'app works!';
      x = ''
      onClearClick() {
        this.x = 'changed';
      };
    }


//spec file
    import { Http, ConnectionBackend, Request, Response, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

    import { TestBed, ComponentFixture, async, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
    import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { DebugElement, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';

    describe('AppComponent', () => {
      let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
      let comp: AppComponent;
      let component: any;
      let MockConnectionBackend = {
        navigate: jasmine.createSpy('ConnectionBackend')
      }
      let MockResponse = {
        navigate: jasmine.createSpy('Response')
      }

      let MockRequestOptions = {
        navigate: jasmine.createSpy('RequestOptions')
      }

      let MockRequest = {
        navigate: jasmine.createSpy('Request')
      }

      beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          declarations: [
            AppComponent
          ],
          providers: [Http,
            { provide: Response, useValue: MockResponse },
            { provide: RequestOptions, useValue: MockRequestOptions },
            { provide: Request, useValue: MockRequest },
            { provide: ConnectionBackend, useValue: MockConnectionBackend }]
        }).compileComponents();
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
      }));



      it('should render title in a h1 tag', async(() => {
        const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
        fixture.detectChanges();
        const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
        expect(compiled.querySelector('h1').textContent).toContain('app works!');
      }));

      it('should', async(() => {
        spyOn(component, 'onClearClick');
        let de: DebugElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#clearSearch'));
        let el: HTMLElement = de.nativeElement;

        fixture.whenStable().then(() => {

          el.click();
          fixture.detectChanges();
          // expect(component.onClearClick).toHaveBeenCalled();
          expect(component.x).toContain('changed');
        })
      }));


    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your test fails because you are spying the method under test without letting the method call through. You also have a bunch of unneeded stuff going on. Try this:

```
it('should change the x value when the button is clicked', () => {
  const rendered = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
  const button = rendered.querySelector('#clearSearch') as HtmlButtonElement;
  button.click():
  expect(component.x).toEqual('changed');
});
```